# Sklearn GridsearchCV with Pipeline and Column transformer returning too few features (GradientBoostingClassifier)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

My preprocessor in my pipeline seems to greatly reduce my features, when it should be increasing.

- my X_train.shape is (1674, 776)
- len(clf.steps[1][1].feature_importances_) = 35

35 is telling as it's exactly the amount of columns expected from one hot encode + standard scaler. Why are my other columns not passing?

How I set up my pipeline:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("scaler", StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', categories='auto'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
            transformers=[
                ('numerical', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
                ('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('classifier', GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=rnd_state))])

clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for `ColumnTransformer`; it has a parameter `remainder` that I suspect you're looking for.  If not, you'll need to provide a smaller data example together with the values of `numeric_features` and `categorical_features`.

Comment: Thanks Ben Reiniger! that was the issue.